# How to change this slime configuration on the init file from the classic imperative installation to a declarative approach via use-package?

Tags: package, use-package, install, slime, declare

When I first installed [Slime](https://github.com/slime/slime), I used to install things via the classic `M-x` and `package-install`. Then, I inserted the following configuration:

```lisp
(slime-setup '(slime-fancy slime-asdf slime-indentation slime-sbcl-exts slime-scratch))

(setq slime-lisp-implementations
      '((sbcl ("/home/pedro/projects/nyxt.sh" ""))))
```

This used to work out. Now, I have moved to a new machine and I have not used classic installation yet (`M-x` and `package-install`).

I want to do **everything** via [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package).

I am especially unsure about how to handle the expressions creating the `slime-setup`.

This is my first attempt:

```lisp
(use-package slime
  :ensure t
  :config
    (setq slime-lisp-implementations
          '((sbcl ("/home/pedro/projects/nyxt.sh" ""))))
    (slime-setup '(slime-fancy slime-asdf slime-indentation slime-sbcl-exts slime-scratch)))
```

After re-starting Emacs, things seem to work fine. However, when I try to start Slime with `M-x` `slime`, the following error message is retrieved:

> apply: Doing vfork: No such file or directory [2 times]